# How can I import a xml bean configuration file to a @configuration class in spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a huge xml that I want to import at it is now on my spring app.

Checking the docs, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html I found I can do something like this

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/resources/applicationContex.xml")
```

My resources folder is under `/src/main`

But I get a file no exists error, any idea if this is the correct way to do it? or is my path wrongly defined?

Comment: Assuming Maven, remove the `/resources` prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Sotirios says in his comment, you should remove the `/resources` prefix. But you're also using the wrong annotation: `@PropertySource` is used to import property files. You should use the `@ImportResource` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class AppConfig {

    // define more beans, wire beans defined in the xml, etc
}
```

Note: You might also have a typo: you were pointing to a file named `applicationContex.xml`. Shouldn't it be `applicationContext.xml` instead? (Note the final `t` before the `.xml` extension).